# Use jQuery to hide text in parentheses

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint, search, sharepoint-2010

I have an image search page on a SharePoint 2010 site. Users can search by keyword and also have the option to filter by image type (e.g., thumbnail, hi-res, etc). So, let's say I search "medicine" and filter the image type by one of the choices, "thumbnail" - I get the following summary at the top of my results page:

**Image Search Results for *medicine* 

*(ImageType="thumbnail")***

What I want is to JUST display the first line, so the search term is included at the top, but NOT the image type (basically all of the text in parentheses). Both lines are wrapped in the same div tag, so I think jQuery will be necessary to hide the parentheses and text inside them.

Here's the HTML and JS for the current setup:

```
<div>
Image Search Results for 
<em>
<script type="text/javascript">
var searchword = document.getElementById('ctl00_g_b54753eb_fcc2_4937_9c5a_3541d9af497b_SE26EBB34_InputKeywords').value;
document.write(searchword)
</script>
medicine (ImageType="thumbnail")
</em>
</div>
```

Comment: Split the string at `(`, then grab the first part.

Comment: You can't just generate the HTML you want, on the server?

Comment: Do you have any control over that HTML structure or it's generated by SharePoint (I know nothing about SharePoint)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you don't want anything after the `(`, then you can just split the string at that character and write it accordingly:

```
var searchword = document.getElementById('ctl00_g_b54753eb_fcc2_4937_9c5a_3541d9af497b_SE26EBB34_InputKeywords').value;
searchword = searchword.split("(")[0];
document.write(searchword)
```

If there is stuff after the `)` that you may want to include, you will have to get a bit fancier. This should work, as long as you are certain to always have only one set of parens:

```
var searchword = document.getElementById('ctl00_g_b54753eb_fcc2_4937_9c5a_3541d9af497b_SE26EBB34_InputKeywords').value;
searchword = searchword.split("(")[0] + searchword.split(")")[1];
document.write(searchword)
```

Comment: I don't believe he has the ability to change the markup, otherwise he could just delete the part he wants.

Comment: @Jonah: There's nothing about markup in my post - just straight javascript.

Comment: I guess I misunderstood the problem.  I don't see how your code changes what's already on the page.

Comment: Well, on a second look, I see where you were coming from. I assumed that where he had written values into the markup above was just as an example of what is currently being output. You assumed that was already hard-coded there. I got lucky and was the one with the correct assumption :)